# Returning additional data in a Solr query result

Tags: solr

I am currently using Solr to do some searching across a large amount of documents. I need to be able to, on the client-side, allow grouping of search results on the fly but I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to get this extra data I need out of Solr and pushed up to the front end.

So basically, let's say I'm searching for the following values: `"Test", "Wee"`

And I have the following documents in Solr:

```
Doc1: "This is a Test, Wee"
Doc2: "Wee"
Doc3: "This is a Test"
```

All 3 documents should be returned by Solr. What I'd like returned is something that contains this:

```
Doc1 matched on values "Test" and "Wee
Doc2 matched on value "Wee"
Doc3 matched on value "Test"
```

I'm a bit new to Solr so I'm having difficulty trying to figure out what to search for. Should I be using faceting for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have only one field you search upon, so faceting won't really help you here (If each value came from a different field, that **might** be possible, what you suggested).
Instead, I suggest you take a look at highlighting utilities, which marks the matched term.
http://wiki.apache.org/solr/HighlightingParameters

Comment: Thanks, I was able to get highlighting working. It seems like there is extra effort as I have to parse the value out of the highlight fields but it at least works for now.

Answer (score 0):

You can consult the output for `debugQuery=true` for a very in-depth look at which terms matched in which documents, and the score calculations used for sorting.